# Why was Æon Flux not pre-screened for critics?

Tags: reception, aeon-flux

In 2005 I had the pleasure to see an animated cartoon brought to life on the big screen: *Æon Flux*. The post-modern architecture, the action, the cheesy lines all paid homage to the MTV cartoon with a good storyline.

Critics detested it, but so did viewers. However, I read that **it was not screened for critics in advance**. I suspect it might have affected their response to the movie. Does not screening for critics happen often?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Does not screening for critics happen often?**

Of course, many films do that. Even in the related [editorial.rottentomatoes.com](https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/Critical-Consensus-Aeon-Flux-Not-Screened-Draw-Your-Own-Conclusions/) discussion about Æon Flux, they listed a few films which were not screened For Critics:

> - In the Mix (2005)
> - The Fog (2005)
> - Cry_Wolf (2005)
> - King’s Ransom (2005)
> - Cursed (2005)

And they got bad reviews from critics after release. But not all films not screened for critics are received badly. There are some exceptions like [*Psycho*](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/psycho/) (1960), where the director wanted to avoid pre critic screening to maintain the suspense and it got mixed to positive critics response.

**Why was Æon Flux not screened for critics?**

I can find no official statement about it from the officials but [Wikipedia listed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_screening#Critic_screenings) two popular reasons for not screening for critics:

> Critic (or "press") screenings are held for national and major market critics well in advance of print and television production-cycle deadlines and are usually by invitation only. This step may be omitted if a **studio anticipates negative critical review**s, or if a **film is still being edited until immediately before release**.